# Joda Time complex operations on time

Tags: parsing, jodatime

I want to use Joda Time in my project. I'd love to know if I have a good idea how to use it.
First of all - I want to make a progress bar that I init and then calculate its value every second - it shows me the time left to complete process.

During initialisation I have only String in format "HH:mm:ss" (ocasionally "D days HH:mm:ss") representing time left and percentage - initial state of progressbar. That is all I have.

Now I want to make a DateTime object that represents the moment of task completion.

```
PeriodFormatter timeFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .appendHours().appendSeparator(":").appendMinutes()
        .appendSeparator(":").appendSeconds().toFormatter();
DateTime endDate_ = new Date();
Period periodLeft = null;
String[] parsedInput = timeLeft.split(" ");
if (parsedInput != null) {
    switch (parsedInput.length) {
    case 1: {
        periodLeft = timeFormatter.parsePeriod(parsedInput[0]);
        endDate_.plus(periodLeft);
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        periodLeft = timeFormatter.parsePeriod(parsedInput[2]);
        periodLeft.plusDays(Integer.parseInt(parsedInput[0]));
        endDate_.plus(periodLeft);
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

As far as I understand now I have what I wanted, right? Now I want to calculate the total duration of process. That is why I convert this period to milliseconds and count total duration on basis of progress:

```
long duration_ = (periodLeft.toStandardDuration().getMillis() * 100) / (progress == 0 ? 1 : progress);
```

Now I have to implement a method that returns actual state of process on basis of current time. How can I achieve that? I know the duration, so I could get the start DateTime. Then I could simply compare current date with start date and count percentage: (now - start)/duration_ * 100. But how can I get the start Date?

Answer (score 0):

Jodatime is very easy to use and you don't need to fill your code with the formatters to get a what you want. What ever the process you are measuring must have started at some point in your code and that is where you should note your start time. Try something like this.

```
 DateTime startTime = DateTime.now();
 DateTime endTime = DateTime.now();
 endTime.plusSeconds(50);


 //Write code for your application.
 //....
 Thread.sleep(3000);

 //Calculate your percentage.
 double remainingPercentage =  (  DateTime.now().getMillis() - startTime.getMillis()) / ( endTime.getMillis() - DateTime.now().getMillis() )*100 ;

//Then output the date using the string method.
 endTime.toString("MMM dd yy ");
```

Comment: This solution is wrong. As I said - I don't have the starting time. Process starts even when my application is off. I solved my problem.

Comment: @user1849493 So where do you get to find the start time? if you don't know when it started then you can't reliably say you have a reliable percentage. Though like you say you solved it. that is good.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I managed to solve it! Function that counts progress is now a bit modified to:

```
if (progress == 0)
    duration_ = periodLeft.toStandardDuration().getMillis();
else
    duration_ = (long) ((periodLeft.toStandardDuration().getMillis() * 100) / (double) (100 - progress));
```

Next thing I do is setting my progressBar max value to duration_ and every second setting value of progress to show to:

```
new Period(startDate_, DateTime.now())
```